# How to change /system/fonts directory permission to writable in switch off mode?

Tags: root-access, fonts

I have Micromax A57 android 2.3.5 rooted phone, I have installed font using "Font Installer  Root" application , after installing successfully I realize that font is not good, then after I delete that font from /system/fonts directory, and I install DroidSans.ttf font from that application, while installing process device get hanged, so I remove battery and place it again and start the device , Now my phone is not started,

when I attach cable with device I can see in Eclipse that in /system/fonts folder DroidSans.ttf has o bytes that means by mistake that font has been deleted, now wants to copy that font in /system/fonts directory, i have tried with Eclipse but it has read only permission so I am failed, If I can copy that file then issue can be solved,

Please help me to change permission of /system/fonts directory so that I can copy that fonts and get my device data back

Answer (score 4):

As it seems you can access your device via ADB, you should be able to remount `/system` read/write to repair that file, using

```
adb remount
```

After that, you can copy the intact `DroidSans.ttf` to `/system/fonts`, overwriting the 0-byte-file. Following a reboot, `/system` will be mounted read-only again, and everything should be working.

---

In case that `adb remount` should fail with a "permission denied", you might wish to read [How to remount /system as read-write in Android](http://ckirbach.wordpress.com/2012/11/27/how-to-remount-system-as-read-write-in-android/), which explains the manual remount process step-by-step. That would basically be:

1. get a shell on the Android device using either `adb shell` or a terminal app
2. become root using `su`
3. find out how and where `/system` is mounted, using `mount | grep system`
4. mount `/system` read/write using the information obtained, e.g. `mount -o rw,remount /dev/block/<device> /system` (make sure to use the device obtained in the previous step instead of `/dev/block/<device>`)
5. verify whether your remount was successful, again using `mount | grep system`
6. now copy your `DroidSans.ttf` to `/system/fonts`
7. either reboot, or simply remount `/system` read-only using the parameters obtained in step 3, e.g. `/dev/block/<device> /system ext4 rw,relatime,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0`

Always make sure to use the device and parameters obtained from step 3, or you might completely mess up.

Comment: Hello Izzy,

Thanks for answer, 
but when I write "adb remount" in command prompt, it says "remount failed: Operation not permitted"

Comment: Exactly for that case I wrote the second part of my answer, below the horizontal ruler. Have you read the part *In case that `adb remount` should fail...*?

Comment: when I enter su after in adb shell it says "su: permission denied"

Comment: Then either your device is not rooted, or you have denied the shell in SuperUser/SuperSU. First time you execute "su", you have to confirm the SuperUser/SuperSU popup on the device itself. If you don't, it will simply timeout and reject the requestor.

Comment: But how can I see popup on device although my device is not being switch on.

Comment: That's in fact a problem: when your device's GUI does not fire up (due to the missing font), the popup cannot be shown. Have you tried to boot into recovery, and work from there?

Comment: yes, I reboot the device in recovery mode by holding up power key, volume up and volume down key together and its working there

Comment: Glad to read! So your issue is solved by this? If so, please indicate by accepting/upvoting the answer :)