# Can't boot because of deleted com.android.launcher2

Tags: boot, restore, launcher

Stupid me deleted the **com.android.launcher2** apk file (located in *system/app*) thinking that my tablet will boot with another launcher I installed and now it doesn't boot up (gets stuck in loading screen).

Now, the tablet's chinese, so I haven't installed a custom bootloader.

I can only get to recovery mode.

I have a backup of everything, (made with an app) on my external SD card, so I did a fac reset (and a cache one), just in case. It did't work.

So now:

**I need to manually copy a file in system/app via system recovery, without a Custom Bootloader.**

I tried making a custom update.zip, with launcher2.apk in it by I get an error "Installation aborted" right after it starts authenticating it.

Is it possible to copy that file without having a custom bootloader, or is there another way to do this (adb commands).

PLEASE help me, I'm really frustrated right now.

Comment: You might wish to take a look at [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/53704/16575). Though it's not about a launcher, it's about how to copy something to `/system` using ADB.